# Storyboard Crash OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, storyboard

I'm seeing this crash happen very randomly:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
    *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: NSViewController-Qmf-WE-Bmb)
0  CoreFoundation                 0x7fff95e504da __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x7fff923eef7e objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x7fff95d4a414 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]
3  AppKit                         0x7fff9857f917 -[NSStoryboard nibForControllerWithIdentifier:]
4  AppKit                         0x7fff9857fc11 -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:]
5  AppKit                         0x7fff982e733b -[NSStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:]
6  AppKit                         0x7fff983345d7 -[NSViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff8e5cc93d _dispatch_call_block_and_release
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff8e5c140b _dispatch_client_callout
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff8e5d4c1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
10 CoreFoundation                 0x7fff95e059e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
11 CoreFoundation                 0x7fff95dc48dd __CFRunLoopRun
12 CoreFoundation                 0x7fff95dc3ed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
13 HIToolbox                      0x7fff99b4b935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode
14 HIToolbox                      0x7fff99b4b76f ReceiveNextEventCommon
15 HIToolbox                      0x7fff99b4b5af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter
16 AppKit                         0x7fff97e3bdf6 _DPSNextEvent
17 AppKit                         0x7fff97e3b226 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
18 AppKit                         0x7fff97e2fd80 -[NSApplication run]
19 AppKit                         0x7fff97df9368 NSApplicationMain
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x7fff8c6875ad start
```

I've verified that the segue identifier is correct and that the storyboard exists and contains the segue. I've also verified that there is a view controller with ID: Qmf-WE-Bmb.

Any clues why this would happen? Does this mean the source VC is deallocated or that its failing to load the destination VC?

Comment: You'd better post your code here.

The fatal exception is **setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil**.

Your object is nil.

Comment: The call is coming from inside NSStoryboard?

Comment: Probably not coming from that.

Comment: I have the same issue. It happens only on macOS Sierra. Verified everything like you.

Comment: This article helped me to find a solution: https://forums.swift.org/t/nsstoryboard-has-no-member-name/13963 which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone hits the same issue, I circumvented the crash by replacing `performSegueWithIdentifier:` with a custom function on my base controller:

```
- (void)performManualSegueWithControllerID:(NSString *)identifier {
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        NSViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (controller) {
            MyCustomAnimator *animator = [[MyCustomAnimator alloc] init];
            [animator setAnimateVertically:NO];
            [self prepareForManualSegueToController:controller];
            [self presentViewController:controller animator:animator];
        } else {
            // Some Error
        }
    } else {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performManualSegueWithControllerID:)
                               withObject:identifier
                            waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForManualSegueToController:(NSViewController *)controller {

}
```